# Which path format to use in C on Windows, "D:\\source.txt" or "D:/source.txt"?

Tags: c, path

I only knew that we can't use `D:\demo.txt` as `\d` will be considered an escape character and hence we have to use `D:\\demo.txt`.But minutes ago I found out that `D:/demo.txt` works just as fine as we don't have to worry about escape characters with `/`. I am using CodeBlocks on Windows, and I want to know which one of these formats for path is valid for  C on my platform.Here's my code and the commented-out lines work just as fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char ch;
FILE *fp,*tp;
fp=fopen("D:\\source.txt","r");
//fp=fopen("D:/source.txt","r");
tp=fopen("D:\\encrypt.txt","w");
//tp=fopen("D:/encrypt.txt","w");
if(fp==NULL||tp==NULL)
printf("ERROR");
while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
putc(~ch,tp);
fclose(fp);
fclose(tp);
}
```

Comment: Both are valid, the forward slash makes fewer headaches.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I use `char path[]="D:\encrypt.txt"` and pass `path` as argument to `fopen()`,it shows **ERROR** through `printf()`,but why it works fine for `char path[]="D:\\encrypt.txt"`?Plz answer this as it's too short for another question.

Comment: I meant both of `"D:\\encrypt.txt"` and `"D:/encrypt.txt"` are valid. You already wrote that you have to escape the backslash in the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer While we write `D:\encrypt.txt` ,it's understandable that `\e` will be mistaken as an escape character,but why so even in `char path[]="D:\encrypt.txt"`

Comment: That's what the language says, a backslash in a string literal (or character constant) signals an escape sequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer But I don't get the warning "Unknown escape...." when I pass `path` as an argument to `fopen()`,even though it can't read the file later and shows **ERROR**.Why I don't get warning while I pass `path`,but I get warning when I write `fopen("D:\encrypt.txt","w")`?

Comment: @DanielFischer After all, as you said,a single backslash is expected to confuse the compiler in `path`,just as much as in `fopen("D:\encrypt.txt","w")`

Comment: It seems `\e` is interpreted as `\ESC`: `.string "D:\033ncrypt.txt"`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks.It was so.It shows error if I  use a path beginning with **m**.

Comment: Maybe you get a warning if you have the literal in the `fopen` call because the compiler knows that a valid filename on Windows can't contain `\ESC` (assuming that's what your compiler interprets `\e` as too)?

Comment: @DanielFischer I am confused about your last comment.You said \e is same as \033.So is `printf("Hello\nJon")` same as `printf("Hello\012Jon")`?

Comment: Usually, yes, if `'\n'` is 10. (If your character set is ASCII compatible; it would probably be something else for EBCDIC.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Umm, but why does `printf("Hello\012Jon")` works but `printf("Hello\10Jon")` doesn't even though 12 octal is decimal 10?

Comment: Because numeric escapes are in octal. Please read some basic C language documentation rather than having extended comment discussions here.

Comment: Because there are no decimal escape sequences in C. Only octal and hexadecimal. `printf("Hello\xaJon");` works too.

Comment: @DanielFischer And why  `printf("Hello\0xAJon");` only prints Hello even though Hex A is same as 012 octal?

Comment: @DanielFischer Why `\xa` works but `\0xA` doesn't?Isnt an hex number supposed to be preceded by `0x` in C?And secondly, why does `\0xA` make the compiler completely **ignore** the second word `Jon` in that `printf()`?

Comment: Hexadecimal escape sequences are started with `\x`, not with `\0x`, so you have a 0-byte after the `"Hello"`. And, you should heed Jim's advice, read a good book about the language, the comments here are not the place to learn it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Last thing,I think I got it.Using \0 means we have used a NULL terminator and hence the string processing ends there,right?Please confirm this last thing.

Comment: Right. Since `'x'` is not an octal digit, the escape sequence consists only of `\0`. If there came octal digits after the 0, those would be part of the escape sequence.

Comment: @Thokchom: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. The terminator for a string is the null *character*, which is a different thing.

Comment: @DanielFischer: If `\e` is being treated as an ASCII escape character, that's a non-standard compiler extension.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right. And gcc tells you that if you ask it to be `-pedantic` (but not by default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows (like MS-DOS before it) requires back-slashes as the path separator for the command line tools built into/provided by Windows.

Internal functions, however, have always accepted forward or backward slashes interchangeably. Personally, I prefer forward slashes as a general rule, but it's mostly personal preference -- either works fine.

Comment: Why don't I get "Unknown escape character \e" warning when I pass `path` as an argument to `fopen()` in my code,but get that warning when I use `fopen("D:\encrypt.txt","w"`?

Comment: When I pass `path` as argument,it compiles without warning,even though later it can't read the file and **ERROR** is printed by the `printf()`.Why the warning is not there when we use a single backslash in `path`'s initialization ,but is so when so use single backslash while passing a string literal directly to `fopen()`?

Comment: The short answer is that it's difficult (if possible at all) to predict why the compiler might give a warning in one case, but not another that may seem essentially similar.

Comment: Why does printf("Hello\012Jon") works but printf("Hello\10Jon") doesn't even though 12 octal is decimal 10?I mean,in first case we get two lines due to the newline,but in second case no newline. And why `printf("Hello\0xAJon");` only prints `Hello` even though Hex A is same as 012 octal?

Comment: @Thokchom: Seems like you're now asking an entirely different question than you were originally -- enough different that it's *probably* going to get the best/most response by asking it as a new, separate question.

Comment: That's the last thing.I am almost done.Why \0xA fails and ignores the remaing part of the format string,while \xA works for newline.

Comment: @Thokchom: `\x` signifies the beginning of a hexadecimal sequence, so `\xa` gives a value of 10. `\0` signifies the beginning of an octal sequence. Since `x` can't be interpreted as octal, you get `\0` followed by `x`, but since the `\0` is interpreted as the end of the string, the `x` gets ignored.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that Windows and MS-DOS accept either the forward slash `/` or the backslash `\` as a directory path delimiter. And there are good arguments for using the forward slash in C code, because it doesn't have to be escaped in string and character literals.

But my own preference is to use the backslash (and remember to escape it properly), because most Windows users likely *don't know* that you can use `/` as a directory delimiter. It doesn't matter for an `fopen` call; these are equivalent (on Windows):

```
fopen("D:\\foo\\bar\\blah.txt", "r");
fopen("D:/foo/bar/blah.txt", "r");
```

But if that file name is ever shown to a user, IMHO it's a lot better if the message refers to `D:\foo\bar\blah.txt`.

You *could* use forward slashes for paths that are used only internally, and backslashes for paths that appear in the user interface, but that's going to be more difficult and error-prone than using one or the other consistently.

Incidentally, the C language says nothing about which character is used as a path delimiter; the language standard doesn't even specify directory support. It's determined by the operating system and file system.